# .gitignore not working for xcuserdata directory in Xcode project

Tags: xcode, git

This is my gitignore file:

```
# Xcode
*.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
*.xcuserstate
project.xcworkspace/
xcuserdata/
```

However, it still detects changes here:

```
BW.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/cooluser.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
```

This is on Xcode 6.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add the `.gitignore` after the file was already being tracked?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The file `BW.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/[...]/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate` must already be tracked by git.

When you add an entry to `.gitignore` it only affects untracked files. If they are already tracked, they are not automatically removed from the repository.

You can remove this file manually with: `git rm --cached BW.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace`